# GUI for Mariadb on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: gui, database

Are there any GUIs for Mariadb on the Raspberry Pi besides phpmysql? I'm hoping for something that's as easy to install as

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found I could use mysql workbench, but there are incompatibility issues. I was hoping I could find something better.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Comment: mysql-workbench is not availble after debian buster.